# PyQt QPlainTextEdit "Command + Backpace" doesn't delete the line on MacOS

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qplaintextedit

Pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> on MacOs normally deletes the current line. 
Is it possible to reproduce this behaviour in `QPlainTextEdit`? It works as expected with `QLineEdit`.

Here's a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence


app = QApplication([])
text = QPlainTextEdit()
window = QMainWindow()
window.setCentralWidget(text)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

I am running the following:
Python 3.6.10
PyQt5 5.14.1
MacOS 10.14.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably subclass QPlainTextEdit and override its keyPressEvent.

As far as I can understand, on MacOS <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> deletes the text *at the left* of the current cursor position, but it's also possible to delete the entire line, no matter what.

In any case:

```
class PlainText(QPlainTextEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Backspace and event.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
            cursor = self.textCursor()

            # use this to remove everything at the left of the cursor:
            cursor.movePosition(cursor.StartOfLine, cursor.KeepAnchor)
            # OR THIS to remove the whole line
            cursor.select(cursor.LineUnderCursor)

            cursor.removeSelectedText()
            event.setAccepted(True)
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
```

Comment: This works! I had to change the if statement to `event.nativeModifiers() == 1048840` thought.